# FastAPI, python, pycharm

Tags: python, fastapi

**my model:**
My model is defined here and when I try to update the details of an entry in my databaseit is giving me an attribute error which I am trying to solve but not getting proper output as I want to update few fields of the database

```
 from sqlalchemy import Column,Integer,String
 from database import Base

class User(Base):
    __tablename__='user'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}

    user_id=Column(Integer,primary_key=True)
    user_name=Column(String)
    f_name=Column(String)
    l_name=Column(String)
    email=Column(String)
    phonenumber=Column(String)
    websiteURL=Column(String)
    websiteDetails=Column(String)
    companyName=Column(String)
    password=Column(String)
    howYouHearAboutUs=Column(String)
```

**my Schemas:**
when i try to update the UsrBase in my put method it is giving me attribute error

```
from pydantic import BaseModel,Field
from typing import List,Optional

class UsrBase(BaseModel):


    user_name:str
    f_name:str
    l_name: str
    email:str
    phonenumber: str
    websiteURL:str
    websiteDetails: str
    companyName: str
    password:str
    howYouHearAboutUs: str

class Usr(UsrBase):
    user_name :str
    class Config():
        orm_mode=True

class ShowUsr(BaseModel):
    user_name:str
    f_name:str
    l_name:str
    companyName:str
    phonenumber:str

    class Config():
        orm_mode=True
```

**when trying to execute the put method the method is not accepting the value for id and not trying to update the values which are there in my fields **

```
from fastapi import APIRouter,Depends,status,HTTPException
from  MerchantRegistration import models,database,hashing
from  MerchantRegistration import schemas
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from typing import List

router=APIRouter()

@router.get('/user', response_model=List[schemas.ShowUsr], tags=['Users'])
def all(db:Session=Depends(database.get_db)):
    users=db.query(models.User).all()
    return users

@router.post('/users/',status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,tags=['Users'],response_model=schemas.ShowUsr)
def create(request:schemas.UsrBase, db:Session=Depends(database.get_db)):
    Lst_of_users= models.User(user_name=request.user_name, f_name=request.f_name,
                             l_name=request.l_name, email=request.email, phonenumber=request.phonenumber,
                             companyName=request.companyName, websiteURL=request.websiteURL, password=hashing.Hash.bcrypt(request.password)
        )

    db.add(Lst_of_users)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(Lst_of_users)
    return Lst_of_users

@router.put('/user/{id}',status_code=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED,tags= 
  ['Users'],response_model=schemas.ShowUsr)
def update(id,request:schemas.UsrBase,db:Session=Depends(database.get_db)):

    usr = db.query(models.User).filter(models.User.user_id == id)

    if not usr.first():
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
                            detail  = f"User with id {id} is not available ")
    usr.update(request)
    db.commit()

    return usr
```

**the error which I am getting when I try to update the details of an Id using the put method**

```
AttributeError: 'UsrBase' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Comment: but UsrBase has no attrib called items? So that's why the error

Comment: but where do I have to declare 'items' as an attribute in my entire post?

Comment: @tiangolo/@fastapi @Sebastián Ramírez

Answer (score 0):

`usr` is a list, so I think where you say

`usr.update(request)`

You should be saying

`usr.first().update(request)`

Comment: have tried this too but still, it is giving me an error only saying AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'update'.